# AutoFocus an input element in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to autofocus the input tag rendered in this component. What am I missing here?

```
class TaskBox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
  }

  focus() {
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  componentWillUpdate(){
    this.focus();
  }

  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{display: props.visible ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
        <input
        ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
        onBlur={props.blurFN} />
        <div>
          <div>Imp.</div>
          <div>Urg.</div>
          <div>Role</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Add goal</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While you're rendering a stateless component, you can just add the tag `autoFocus` to your input element and it will auto focus the element.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is a attribute available for auto focusing `autoFocus`, we can use that for auto focusing of input element instead of using `ref`.

Using `autoFocus` with input element:

`<input autoFocus />`

We can also use `ref`, but with ref we need to call focus method at correct place, you are calling that in `componentWillUpdate` lifecycle method, that method will not triggered during initial rendering, Instead of that use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.focus();
}
```

**[shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)**: is always called before the render method and enables to define if a re-rendering is needed or can be skipped. Obviously this method is never called on initial rendering. It will get called only when some state change happen in the component.

**[componentWillUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)** gets called as soon as the the `shouldComponentUpdate` returned true.

**[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)**: As soon as the render method has been executed the componentDidMount function is called. The DOM can be accessed in this method, enabling to define DOM manipulations or data fetching operations. Any DOM interactions should always happen in this.

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: exactly! I just realised it. It started working componentDidMount. Why cant we focus in  componentWillUpdate? one is before the rendering is done and the other post it, and this is triggerd for a state change.

@mayank is this because the parent component was in `display: none` mode while the rendering is taking place?

So that means if we `display: none` an input HTML tag, and then focus it programmatically and after it, display it(`display: block`), focus wont work.

Am I thinking in the right manner?

Comment: componentWillUpdate will not get called on first rendering, componentDidMount will get called just after the rendering, so you need to focus the input element in this method, check the updated answer :)

Comment: `componentDidMount` will only execute after `render()` in mount phase of life cycle. So, It is only correct for `mounting` phase. For update lifecycle it is not correct.

Comment: you can also have it called in componentDidUpdate.

Comment: Yes! `autofocus` doesn't work, but `autoFocus` does. It wasn't trivial to learn that, as google results don't seem to mention this attribute.

Comment: and what if I am not working with a class component and I don't have the capability to change it?

Answer (score -14):

Set an ID to the input and then use `.setAttribute('autoFocus', true)` to the element when you want it focused