# React autoFocus attribute is not rendered

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render an `<input>` field with `autofocus`:

```
<input type="text" autoComplete="off" autoFocus={true} className="form-control" />
```

But it's being rendered as:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
```

And the input does not focus.

**Why is that?** How can I get the `autofocus` attribute to render?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AutoFocus an input element in react JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42324423/autofocus-an-input-element-in-react-js)

Comment: That uses an old method

Comment: @norbitrial It doesn't: I already tried the suggestion to use the `autoFocus` attribute in JSX, and it's **not** rendering the `autofocus` HTML attribute. People, please don't jump on the Close button too fast; this is a different question.

Comment: You can use `document.activeElement` in the console to figure out what is actually being focused. 

Does this help?: https://davidwalsh.name/react-autofocus

Comment: The most important question is, does it auto focus? If it does, then it doesn't matter that it isn't being rendered.

Comment: @BrandonDyer it does not focus, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @GregM `document.activeElement` returns the `<div>` of the React Bootstrap `<Modal>` component my input lives in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is expected, actually. React will manually call `focus()` on the relevant element, but it will not add the attribute itself.

Here is a quote from Dan Abramov from a [ticket response](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11851#issuecomment-351672131) from ~2 years ago:

> This is intentional because it works very differently in different browsers. So instead of actually setting a DOM attribute, we polyfill its behavior in JavaScript.

Also, from another [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11159#issuecomment-335836758):

> Chrome respects dynamically added elements with autoFocus if there hasn’t been one before. Even creating an input with autoFocus, adding it to the document, and removing it in the next tick is enough to disable autofocusing of any elements added in the future in Chrome.
>
> Firefox just doesn’t care about any dynamically added elements with autoFocus at all.
>
> And Safari always respects them.

---

That being said, you *could* still force the attribute with `autofocus="true"` instead of `autoFocus={true}` but it might not actually work in a reliable fashion. After all, there is a reason the React team polyfilled this.

In other words, if you want a reliable, consistent cross-browser behavior use `autoFocus`, if you *must* have the native attribute you can use `autofocus="true"`, but know that you'll be at the mercy of letting the browser decide when and how said element will be focused.

Comment: Thank you, very informative. The issue then is, why doesn't it focus when the element is rendered? (I forgot to mention that!)

Comment: Most likely due to something else in your application that might interfere. Are you using `autoFocus` elsewhere?

Comment: No, this is the only usage. And there can be at most one instance of this component rendered at any given time.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was asking - just in case :) Not sure what might be causing it. Here is a working example, just for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-6gzii

Comment: As I said in the comments above, the `<div>` of the containing `<Modal>` is selected instead, not sure why. Thanks for your example, although I had to fix it: `ReferenceError - Todo is not defined` (`<Todo>` instead of `<App>`). Strangely, it does not autofocus either for me!

Comment: Yes, it didn't save for some reason. I updated the link a moment ago.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, are you absolutely sure that `document.activeElement` returns a div? Seems weird. Maybe that div has `tabindex` or something?

Comment: I'm using Chrome & Firefox. I'm sure, and yes it does have `tabindex`: `<div class="fade modal show" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="true">`.

Comment: It's hard to tell but it might be something with your modal "stealing" the focus. `autoFocus` still works. :)

Comment: Sure. I still can't get it to work with my use case, however. The modal is definitely stealing the focus, probably *after* the `autoFocus` triggers. I've resorted to using a `ref` instead, and manually calling `.focus()` in `componentDidMount()`. Better than nothing, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a ref, and setting the focus when your component is ready.

```js
const YourComponent = (props) => {
    const inputEl = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        inputEl.current.focus();
    }, []);

    return <div>
        <input autofocus="true" ref={inputEl} />
    </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Brandon works perfectly. Additionally, if you want to autofocus on an input on a Modal for example, just keep track of the modal state and use that to focus. For example:

```js
const refModal = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if(modalOpen) {
        refModal.current.focus();
    }
}, [modalOpen]);
```