# React autoFocus missing from DOM element

Tags: reactjs, autofocus

I'm setting `autoFocus` on an input element in React which is normal practice.

```
<input className="form__input" type="text" value={name} onChange={toValue(setName)} autoFocus required></input>
```

When my component is rendered with this code and I look in DevTools there is no `autoFocus` or `autofocus` property on the element.

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Does the input get focus in initial load though?

Comment: If I have that form UI open on load, yes. However, I'm wanting to find the `autoFocus` elements because I have to do that manually when the form UI is shown.

Comment: Did you try doing that with ref? Give that input a ref, call inputRef.current.focus() on useEffect. I don't quite understand why you need to find autoFocus on dom tree.

Comment: @zimmerbimmer, shouldn't it be enough that I do? I'm trying to create a modal component library because I think that the existing ones are too awkward. I want people who use this library to be able to set autoFocus on an element and have it work. HTML5 isn't smart enough to do this so I have to do it myself.  Forcing my users to do anything other than set autoFocus makes my library just as ugly as the existing ones. I need to find a hack to make this work. It is going to be really nice if it can work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [React autoFocus attribute is not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216787/react-autofocus-attribute-is-not-rendered)