# Focus input after modal appear React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a custom Modal. This modal appears after clicking on a button. The modal contains inputs. Input is also a component.

**Input component**,

```
<ModalInput label="Name" focus={true} />
```

**ModalInput.jsx**,

```
const ModalInput = ({ label, focus }) => {
  return (
    <div className="input-row">
      <div className="label">{label}</div>
      <input autoFocus={focus} type="text" style={{ width: "300px" }} />
    </div>
  );
};

ModalInput.defaultProps = {
  focus: false,
};

export default ModalInput;
```

I'm passing a prop called `focus` with the input component. The default value is false. But hereafter the modal appears it's not focusing on the input.

Comment: That looks like it should work, is anything else requesting focus elsewhere on the page?

Comment: No, just only that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this conversation telling that this is an expected behavior.

[React autoFocus attribute is not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216787/react-autofocus-attribute-is-not-rendered)

You can use an `useRef` and set the focus when the component is ready:

```
    const inputEl = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        inputEl.current.focus();
    }, []);

    return <div>
        <input autofocus="true" ref={inputEl} />
    </div>;
}
```