# Input field activated without having to be clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to be able to type in an input field without clicking on it when my page loads. So when the browser is open, I can already start typing on it. My application is built with React.

I tried the autofocus attribute in the input tag but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you use `autofocus` or `autoFocus`? Case matters here as it is a React synthetic attribute for cross browser support. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-frost-qk3j3w?file=/src/App.js) see: [React autoFocus attribute is not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216787/react-autofocus-attribute-is-not-rendered)

Comment: Also listed in the docs: [input: props](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/components/input#props)

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried with `useRef` hook?

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <input type="text" ref={ref} />
  );
};
```

Comment: This is correct but overkill. Simply using the appropriate `autoFocus` property works fine.

Comment: Agreed, but looks like it’s not working for @Hilary. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that they used the wrong case `autofocus` instead of `autoFocus` which is why I commented with further resources above as well as a working sandbox. I also voted to close for debugging details because the description was vague.

Comment: It was the typo. Thank you so much!